# Shopify API POST for Private App to Create Fulfillment

Tags: curl, terminal

Below is what I am passing to Shopify:

```
curl -v -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: 1fadecf1b0eee641ce0248e3b5f053XX" -X POST "https://[key]:[pass]@[store].myshopify.com/admin/orders/361911625/fulfillments.json" -d '{"fulfillment":{"tracking_numbers":["1Z89E5W203624344XX"],"line_items":[{"id":640901329}],"notify_customer":"true"}}'
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Server: nginx Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 15:59:22 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: close Vary: Accept-Encoding Vary: Accept-Encoding Status: 404 Not Found X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=/xss-report/ec54beef-a112-4fb7-a19a-b76a6960616a?source%5Baction%5D=create&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Ffulfillments&source%5Bsection%5D=admin X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1 X-ShopId: 4XXX5XX X-ShardId: 2 X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 1/40 HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 1/40 X-Stats-UserId: 0 X-Stats-ApiClientId: 513097 X-Stats-ApiPermissionId: 9286803 X-Request-Id: ec54beef-a112-4fb7-a19a-b76a696061XX

{"errors":"Not Found"}
```

I am working in PHP, have tried using PHP based curl functions, curl_init, setopt, curl_exec... but was getting the same results so tried switch to command line.  When searching around online I tried every "fix" I could locate, but none seemed to be my cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
curl -v -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST "https://KEY:PASSWORD@YOURSHOP.myshopify.com/admin/orders/381824040/fulfillments.json" -d '{"fulfillment":{"notify_customer":true,"tracking_numbers":["ce09af9e9cc42f4b6306d7de4b6ad655"],"line_items":[{"id":682326640}]}}'
```

If you're still having trouble, double check the order ID and the line item ID.

Note that with private apps, you don't need the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` and there shouldn't be quotes around the `true` value on `notify_customer`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I confused the `line_items` `id` with `variant` `id`.

I understood that when I got 404 error for `/admin/orders/381824040/fulfillments.json` with `line_items`

And then got success for `/admin/orders/381824040/fulfillments.json` without `line_items`.